# Is there a list of rules for Penn & Teller: Fool Us?

Tags: penn-and-teller-fool-us

In particular (but not limited to) rules for:

1. What the magicians aren't allowed to do
2. What the magicians are allowed to do
3. How Penn & Teller decide whether they've been fooled
4. How the judges decide whether Penn & Teller have been fooled (When Penn & Teller go to the judges, when the judges can overrule Penn & Teller)

In particular and for example:

- Are communications with off-stage assistants and assistance with electronic devices allowed?
- Is instant stooging allowed?

Penn & Teller frequently state that stooges, pre-show work, and setups are not allowed, but for example, in S08E05, Micah ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6kTsiD8dypA)) does a trick that is easily explained with instant stooging ([Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/FoolUs/comments/qnlt34/season_8_episode_5_discussion_thread_teller_gets/)), but inexplicable otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

It's not available on the internet (*real* evidence), and many of these rules may not be public as they're part of contracts between professionals, with [Non-Disclosure Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement) (NDA). I think we can guess some of them though.

**What the magicians aren't allowed to do?**

These are rules of common sense, I don't think they should have to be written down though, but they *might* be in contract, to protect the producer of possible futur lawsuits.

1. don't harm people/animals.
2. don't break the law.
3. use common sense/cleverness/humour and respect people at all times.

**What the magicians are allowed to do?**

I would say anything that doesn't go against the first 3 rules.
They may have more things they're not allowed to do, but contracts aren't usually disclosed to third parties, such as...well, us.

**How Penn & Teller decide whether they've been fooled?**

> Among veteran conjurers, though, tricks are almost always decipherable—if not in precise mechanics, then in theory and technique.<sup>[1]</sup>

They probably decide that they've been fooled when they can't tell the magician the trick he used.

**How the judges decide whether Penn & Teller have been fooled?**

Probably by comparing their own experience, and the magician's trick vs P & T explanation. In order to be able to be fair and accurate, they know the trick beforehand. P & T can be close in spirit/technique, or not. Only professionals will tell. So they judge if P & T are close enough to the truth. They may use the sames technics and parameters as the ones explained by Nina Strochlic and Michael Greshko in their National Geographic article<sup>[1]</sup>. But fact is that people often fail to see things even when they are looking straight at them. So don't be so sure to trust your vision in the future<sup>[2]</sup>. You never know what's really happening. Penn & Teller and the jury **are** pros, they exactly know where and what to watch <sup>[2][3]</sup>. That'll help them set the *did or did not* fool gauge.<sup>[3]</sup>

> A backstage judge or judges, versed in the techniques of the magic industry and privately informed how the trick is done prior to the show, makes any necessary calls whether Penn & Teller were properly fooled. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penn_%26_Teller:_Fool_Us)

**Are communications with off-stage assistants and assistance with electronic devices allowed? Is instant stooging allowed?**

I found no evidence, either way. Maybe an insider would know and disclose some tricks, but I'm afraid people working on said shows have strong and powerful NDA.

**TL;DR**: These are just my 2 cents, but never forget that magic tricks are just that: tricks. And to remain fun (for all ages) and entertaining, they need to remain just that: *tricks* to sparkle and shine kid's (and grown up's) eyes. So it could be better if we didn't know the answer to your question :)

---

<sup>1. [How does a magician trick other magicians?](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/culture/article/fism-magician-world-championships)</sup>

<sup>2. [Tricking the brain: how magic works](https://www.all-about-psychology.com/tricking-the-brain-how-magic-works.html)</sup>

<sup>3. Magic relies on powerful psychological illusions and magicians create their tricks by exploiting gaps and errors in our conscious experience. For example, magicians use misdirection to manipulate what you attend to and this allows them to control what you see – and what you miss. [The Guardian - What magic reveals about how our brains work](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2019/mar/30/mind-games-what-magic-reveals-about-how-our-brains-work)</sup>

Comment: The acts have to give the explanation to the judges beforehand. All they have to do is spot whether Penn's codewords and responses from the act match the explanation.

Comment: @OrangeDog : yes, they know beforehand (or it wouldn't be 'magic' but 'cheating'), and they compare "*the magician's trick vs P&T explanation*", as explained by NG "*tricks are almost always decipherable—if not in precise mechanics, then in theory and technique*". I'm pretty sure judges compare the explanation of P&T to the real explanation given by the magician. P&T can be close in spirit/technique, or not. Only professionals will tell.

Comment: You seemed to be implying that the judges also had to work it out.

Comment: oh ok no! I'll try to reorganize my words/sentences then, to make it more clear. Better now?